# macOS: ps's columns "nswap nvcsw majflt minflt" are always empty, values are correct in top

Tags: process, macos, ps, top

Is there a system setting to enable reporting "nswap nvcsw majflt minflt" for `ps` on macOS? These fields are listed in the manual installed on macOS, but their column is always empty (shows `-`). The weirder part is that FAULTS column in `top` (top's equivalent of majflt) command shows what looks like true values for page faults.

Here's a sample command:

```
ps ax -o 'pid nswap nvcsw majflt minflt command'
```

Relevant system info:

- macOS version: 12.5
- architecture: aarch64 (or marketing term "Apple Silicon")
- model/CPU: Apple M1 Max
- SIP (System Integrity Protection): doesn't matter, tried with both disabled and enabled